# Switching To Routers in FastApi did not go well. response_model List[] pydantic field type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I have a Python 3.8 app that uses FastApi. There were getting to be too many routes in `main.py` so I embraced switching from FastApi `application` object to the `router` and putting a route per db table in its own file. So far it has not worked due to interpretation of the `response_model` decorator.

The switch has caused my modified code to have trouble with the response_model decorators `Post`. The biggest difference is I am using the `router` decorator as opposed to the `application` decorator in main.

The specific error I am getting is:

```
 File "/Users/markwardell/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/utils.py", line 67, in create_response_field
    raise fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError(
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that typing.List[models.Post] is a valid pydantic field type
```

The code that is causing this error is here in `post.py` where I broke it out from main.py

**post.py**

from fastapi import HTTPException,  APIRouter
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from typing import List
from fastapi.params import Depends

```
import models
from database import get_db

router: APIRouter = APIRouter()


@router.get("/postss", response_model=List[models.Post])
def get_post(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    # cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM posts""")
    # posts = cursor.fetchall()
    # print(posts)

    try:
        posts = db.query(models.Post).all()
    except Exception as ex:
        msg = f"Unexpected {ex=}, {type(ex)=}"
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=msg)
    return posts
```

The original code which works:

**main.py**

from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, HTTPException
from fastapi.params import Depends
from starlette import status
import user
import post

```
import models
import schemas
from database import engine, get_db
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(user.router)
app.include_router(post.router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Welcome To My Api!"}


@app.get("/posts", response_model=List[schemas.Post])
def get_posts(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    # cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM posts""")
    # posts = cursor.fetchall()
    # print(posts)

    try:
        posts = db.query(models.Post).all()
    except Exception as ex:
        msg = f"Unexpected {ex=}, {type(ex)=}"
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=msg)
    return posts
```

here is the definition of the response_model(s)

**schema.py**

```
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr


class PostBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool = True


class PostCreate(BaseModel):
    pass


class Post(PostBase):
    id: int
    created_at: datetime

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


class UserCreate(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: str


class UserOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    email: EmailStr
    created_at: datetime

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Comment: You're using `models.Post` - that seems like a different class (i.e. your internal database model) than what you intended to use - `schemas.Post`?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks. If you decide to answer this I will mark as answered. If not I will delete question tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong type of class in your `response_model` definition; the reference should point to your schema (which inherits from pydantic's `BaseModel`) - your `response_model` points to your SQLAlchemy model (i.e. `schema` vs `model` in your module name).